# Why does my React UI only update in many cases when I delete the '.parcel-cache' and 'dist' folders and restart the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parcel

The problem arises when I make changes to the code within the Body component. Interestingly, I can observe live updates using an autosave extension. However, within the Body component, there is another subcomponent, and when I make changes to it, the updates are not reflected in the UI in real-time.

The peculiar aspect is that, upon stopping the server, deleting the '.parcel-cache' and 'dist' folders, and restarting the server, the updates in the subcomponent are then accurately reflected.

I attempted several troubleshooting steps to address the issue:

1 - Added this in script = "start": "parcel index.html && parcel watch index.html",
2 - Deleted the 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json', followed by a reinstallation.
3 - Disabled the auto-save extension and manually saved the changes.
4 - Updated and restarted Visual Studio Code.
5 - My files are not in any cloud; all files are in my local storage

Despite these efforts, the problem persists, and the updates to the subcomponent within the Body component are not reflected in the UI in real-time. I'm seeking assistance to understand why these changes require manual intervention with cache deletion and server restart to take effect.

I am encountering a peculiar issue with my React application. The versions of the key dependencies are as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "food-ordering-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "food ordering app using react and parcel bundle",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html && parcel watch index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.11.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1"
  }
}
```